# Display Futures From the Leftmost Bar at Zero to the Current Bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to display the ES futures price as an orange line that starts at 0 at the leftmost part of the visible range and stops with the most current bar. If the visible range changes, so does the zero point with it, it's always located at the leftmost part of the visible range.

This is the pinescript code that I have so far to achieve this task:

```
//@version=5
indicator("ES Futures from Leftmost Bar", overlay=true)

//Get the ES futures data using the current timeframe
es = request.security("ES1!", timeframe.period, close)

//Calculate the index of the leftmost bar of the visible range
leftmostBarIndex = bar_index - ta.barssince(barstate.isconfirmed)

//Calculate the difference between the ES futures and the leftmost bar
diff = es - es[leftmostBarIndex]

//Plot
plot(diff, title="ES Futures", color=color.new(color.rgb(255, 165, 0), 0), linewidth=2)
```

I'm getting a 7033 error, too many candles in history were referenced.

Is there no way to achieve this without an error message?